# Drupal 7.12: content type select widget not working

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

for some reason i cannot select a widget when adding fields in my content types.

[image]

when i select a 'type of data to store', it automatically populates the form element section but i cannot change the option nor can i save the field. Has Anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: I would try to update jQeuery library that came with drupal with a newer version from www.jquery.com if possible.

Comment: thank you very much, it was the jquery. i changed it from v1.7 to v1.5 and its now working. I had changed it to v1.7 hoping for better performance. thanks again.